# How to write an xml file using ajax

Tags: xml, ajax

Am trying to create and write an XML file using Ajax. My scenario is i have a Log in window in my mobile web app when the user enter the username and password the data entered should sent to the server through the XML file.

In this, i need to create and write the XML file with the elements of username and password through Ajax. I Google and not got clear idea for how to achieve it.

My Doubts are,

- Can i create an XML file using Ajax.
- If so how can i create and write the XML elements from Ajax.

Can anyone suggest me an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have a Log in window in my mobile web app when the user enter the username and password the data entered should sent to the server through the XML file

Using XML would massively overcomplicate that task. Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded data would be much simpler.

> Can i create an XML file using Ajax

No. You can make an HTTP Request using Ajax.

You could make that HTTP Request a POST request, and include an XML document in the body of it.

> If so how can i create and write the XML elements from Ajax.

If I was to do that (which I wouldn't, see above), I'd store a template XML document in a string, parse it with a DOM parser, manipulate it to add the data, then serialise it back to XML. See [Parsing and serializing XML at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML)